# Why do I keep timing out on Minecraft multiplayer servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I join a multiplayer server I get to play for around five minutes, it loads the chunk and lets me interact with furnaces, ect. but after some time it disconnects me and says 'Timed Out', my friends don't get disconnected to the server though. When I check my internet it says I'm connected. What's going on?

Comment: Does this only happen with a specific server or all servers?

Comment: All multiplayer servers

Comment: How reliable is your connection otherwise? Have you played other online games with it?

Comment: It's pretty unreliable, it disconnects me a lot and goes on limited, I play Sims 4, which doesn't need internet connection, but you can use internet and it disconnects there also. However, when I get disconnected from a server my internet usually is connected.

Comment: If you're having general internet issues, try asking on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). They're better at tech support than Arqade (we focus more on playing games).

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problems with my own router. Unfortunately, a lot of it is due to high Internet usage from the rest of my family and a low available connection. (The only service available in my area is 3 Mbps.)

I would guess the problem is not with your router, but with your internet provider. Check which speed you currently have and see if faster services are available if you are willing to pay more.

Otherwise, others in your house using streaming services like Netflix or Pandora will GREATLY increase the issues with connection. If you can plug an Ethernet cable directly into the device you are using, this may help increase reliability.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in a comment, your connection is very unreliable. As a result, you will have trouble playing any Internet-based game, not just Minecraft, because packets are lost every time you lose connection to the Internet.

The most frequent cause of intermittent outages can be traced to your router or modem, which is very often supplied by your ISP. If you are certain that it is not your router, you should contact your ISP and ask them to diagnose or replace your modem.